# Equilibrium temperature distribution in PDE in polar coordinates

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, heat-equation

> Determine the equilibrium temperature distribution inside a circular annulus ($r_1\le r\le r_2$) if the outer radius is at temperature $T_2$ and the inner radius is at temperature $T_1$.

The corresponding heat equation in polar coordinates can be expressed as follows:

$$\nabla^2u=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial \theta^2}=0$$

In our case there is no dependence on $\theta$, so we can set the second derivative of $u$ with respect to $\theta$ in our equation to $0$. Thus we get an ordinary differential equation:

$$\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{du}{dr}\right)=0,$$

which is an Euler-Cauchy equation. Solving with the boundary conditions $u(r_1)=T_1$ and $u(r_2)=T_2$ we get:

$$u(r)=\frac{(T_1 - T_2) \log(r) + T_2 \log(r_1) - T_1 \log(r_2)}{\log(r_1) - \log(r_2)}$$

Please let me know if this approach is correct.

Comment: That's correct.